# awk: search for a string, but only inside a range

Tags: bash, awk

I want to search for a string in a file, and print that line plus the line preceding it, but only **after** the line where string XXX appears in the file. How can I achieve this?

Here is an example: search for lines containing the string "### records", but only after the line that says "start real work"

INPUT FILE

```
cat << EOF > x.x
start job
initialization
20 records

start real work


first step
30 records

# comments
second step
0 records

#comments
third step
22 records

end
EOF
```

AWK ONE-LINER - This searches through the whole file, I can't figure out how to only start searching for the string "#### records" after the line that says "start real work"

```
awk '/records/ && !/^0 records/{for(i=1;i<=x;)print a[i++];print} \
{for(i=1;i<x;i++)a[i]=a[i+1];a[x]=$0;}' x=1 x.x
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
first step
30 records
third step
22 records
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
/start real work/{
  found=1
  next
}
val && /records/{
  if($1>0){
    print val ORS $0
  }
  val=""
  next
}
found && NF && !/#/{
  val=$0
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
/start real work/{        ##Check if line contains start real work then do following.
  found=1                 ##Setting found to 1 here.
  next                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
val && /records/{         ##Checking if val is set and line contains records then do following.
  if($1>0){               ##Check if 1st field is greater than 0 then do following.
    print val ORS $0      ##printing val ORS and current line here.
  }
  val=""                  ##Nullifying val here.
  next                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && NF && !/#/{      ##Checking if found is SET and NF is NOT NULL and lines is not having #
  val=$0                  ##Then set val to current line.
}
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
    /start real work/            { inWork = 1 }
    inWork && /^[1-9].* records/ { print prev ORS $0 }
    { prev = $0 }
' file
first step
30 records
third step
22 records
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^start real work/{flag=1} flag && !/[0-9]{2}/{lastline=$0} flag && /^[0-9]{2} records/{print lastline;print}' x.x
first step
30 records
third step
22 records
```

note:
your problem description does not mention anything about the "step" lines shown your output.

The idea is to set a flag when you see the signal to begin and check the flag along with any other test you may require.

If the flag is set and a line is not a valid "records" line,
then stash it  (as lastline).

If the flag is set and the line is a valid two digit "records" line then output the stashed line and then the current line.

Comment: Naming a flag variable `flag` is like naming a numeric variable `number` instead of `sum` or `cnt` or `ave` or `tot` or `lineNr` or something that tells you what the variable holds. You should never have a variable named `flag`, it should at least be `found` to indicate you found something in the input. When people use a flag variable named `f` in their code it's shorthand for `found`, not for `flag`.

Comment: "note: your problem description does not mention anything about the "step" lines shown your output." My awk one-line was not pasted correctly, I fixed that. I want to show the "step" lines because in my original problem description I said "print that line plus the line preceding it", i.e. I want to show the line above the "records" line also. But thank you, your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` in paragraph mode:

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n'  -v OFS='\n' '
        /start real work/ {f=1;next}
        f && (/records/ && !/^#/)
        f && (/^#/ && $3 !~ /^0/) {print $2,$3}
' file
first step
30 records
third step
22 records
```